# What do $x$ and $y$ represent in the wave equation?

Tags: waves, acoustics

for example:

$$y=\frac{10}{5+(x+2t)^2}$$

if this is an equation for a wave

what do $x$ and $y$ actually tell?
I have read some books and according to  them x is the displacement of the wave and y is also the displacement of the disturbance

what exactly is a disturbance??

What does it mean?

[image]

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A valid wave equation is usually established on a Cartesian coordinate system where the wave generating object (e.g., the hand in the picture) is located at the origin, and the equation is a function of x, y, and t.  To observe a particular piece of the spring that is shown in the picture, one must specify where the piece of spring is (the x coordinate).  Then, as the waves periodically pass that point, the piece of the spring moves up and down (the y coordinate) in time ("t" in the wave equation).  Thus, to find out where a particular piece of that spring is, one specifies x and t, and calculates the value of y.

Of note: the example equation is not a sinusoidal wave equation, which is what is required to represent the given picture.

Comment: The example is a *solution* to the standard partial differential equation for a wave. If has the same form as the general d'Alembert solution $F(x+ct) + G(x-ct)$ where $F$ and $G$ are arbitrary functions. There is no reason why waves have to be "sinusoidal". But of course the OP's picture of a wave is not the same as the equation.

Comment: @alephzero, I modified my comment in the answer.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: thanks but can  i get another  example??

Comment: @MeetLalwani, could you be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

The term '[wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation)' is reserved for a different concept: the equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}
$$
(or its generalization to three spatial dimensions), which is a [partial differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation) that governs a wave. In this version, $t$ is time and $c$ is the speed of the wave, and the wave is in one dimension along the coordinate $x$; the wave quantity $u$ can be a bunch of things (say, pressure, electric field, displacement of some medium, etc.), depending on what wave is being modelled.

The *solutions* of the wave equation are functions $u=u(x,t)$ of the spatial coordinate (in this case $x$ and time, such as, like in your example,
$$
u(x,t) = \frac{a}{b+(x-ct)^2},
$$
with $a$ and $b$ constants. These solutions are *not* known as 'wave equations'; the correct term is *waveform*. (For completeness, note that the waveform you've written does *not* correspond to the diagram you provided.)

For many waves, such as gravity waves on the surface of water or elastic waves on a string or a slinky, the wave quantity $u$ is a displacement, which can be along the same direction as $x$ (such as with compressive waves in a slinky) or orthogonal to it. If the symbol $u$ is being used in the place of $u$, then it is likely that the text is describing a transverse wave in which the wave quantity is a displacement along a direction orthogonal to the propagation direction ($x$).

... but that's *all* you can say. Notation is wide and varied, and every author is free to use it as they see fit, and in the way that will best help communicate what they want to write about. The one requirement is that the assignment of symbols needs to be unambiguous and it needs to be suitable explained.

So, in that regard, the *only* valid answer to "what do $x$ and $y$ mean?" is to **check the details of the text that's using them**. If the text does not provide a clear and unambiguous definition, *find a better text*.

Different bits of notation can and do mean different things in different books, so complaining that the same term means different things in different sources is no different to reading a bunch of novels and then complaining that in some of them the protagonist was called "Harry" and in another one the protagonist was called "Frodo".

Comment: @MeetLalwani Please take your time to compose complete comments with correct grammar. If you do not take the time to do this, you are essentially saying that it is not worth it for me to devote any similar time to answering your questions.

Comment: I'm sorry for using bad grammar but ur answer really helped me. I would appreciate it if u could give me another example.

Comment: "another example" of what?

Comment: I am really sorry my thoughts arent as clear as yours. All I want to know is  what exactly would x and y represent in a wave on a string

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of waves that can propagate on a water surface, so-called solitary wave, a special example of solitons, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton . In your question the wave moves with speed $-2$ in whatever units you are using. In general, the moving "hump", wave, is a two-variable function mathematically described as $y(x,t)=f(x-vt)$ where $x$ is the propagated distance from some arbitrary reference point so that $x=0$ when $t=0$, $t$ is the elapsed time, $y$ is the vertical displacement at location $x$ at t instant $t$, and $v$ is the velocity of the "hump" as it travels along $x$. For a non-linear dispersive system such as surface gravity waves the two effects non-linearity and dispersion work balance each other so that such wave can exist. Because of non-linearity the wave amplitude and the wave speed are related and not independent.

The same kind of solitary wave can also exist at the interface of two non-viscid liquids, for example, in the ocean at the interface of the upper warm mixed water and the lower colder, denser, saltier layer (thermocline).